# Regarding this SQL query, how can I output list of 28/30/31 days according to user's choice of certain month and year

Tags: sql, vb.net, stored-procedures

I've declared all the variables right here.

```
    declare @FromDate as datetime;
    declare @ToDate as datetime;
    declare @OperID as varchar(20) = 'OP1';
    declare @Year as int = 2018
    declare @Month as int = 1

 set @FromDate = convert(date,convert(varchar,@Year) + '-' + 
    convert(varchar,@Month) + '-01')
    set @ToDate = dateadd(d,-1,DATEADD(m, 1, @FromDate))
```

This is the body of the query, I want to output Branch_No,operid is Staff ID, Clock_date is the day of the clock In and clock Out , [I] stands for clock in ,
[O] stands for clock Out.

```
    select Branch_no, operid, clock_date, [I], [O]
    from
    ( select Branch_no, operid, 
    convert(date, clock_date) as clock_date, 
    convert(time, clock_date) as clock_time, 
    clock_type, Workstation_no
    from ROSTER_TIMECLOCK
    where Clock_date >=CONVERT(DATETIME, @FromDate, 102)
    and Clock_date <=CONVERT(DATETIME, @ToDate, 102)
    and OperID=@OperID  ) as TheClock
```

Then, I use Pivot to combine the query to show the data in column like this

Branch Number |Clock Date | Staff ID | IN | OUT

```
   PIVOT
  ( min(clock_time)
  FOR clock_type in ([I],[O])
  ) as ThePivot
```

[The Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4qkn.jpg)

Comment: Do you mean output dates from 1 to 28 or 30 or 31 whether or not there are entries for these dates in your table?

Comment: I mean , 1st to 28th for February, and  basically it follows how many days the selected month has, let's say  user choose january for month and 2018 for year, then it will list all the days of the month .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Create procedure procname
@year int,
@month int
As
(Rest of the code goes here)
```

Remove the declaration of year and month.

Comment: Sir, how I can replace the "insert into @inout"  and the content with different month,year and operID with variables? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary table that contains all the dates for the selected period, then do a left join on your output table, like the following:

```
Create procedure nameofsp
@year int,
@month int
As

declare @FromDate as datetime
declare @ToDate datetime
declare @OperID varchar( 20 )  

set @FromDate = convert(datetime,convert(varchar,@Year) + '-' + 
    convert(varchar,@Month) + '-01')
    set @ToDate = dateadd(d,-1,DATEADD(m, 1, @FromDate))

--  create a table that contains all the dates for the period selected
declare @dates table( currentdate datetime )
;with cte( curr )
as
(
    select @fromdate
    union all
    select dateadd( d, 1, curr )
        from cte 
        where curr < @todate
)
insert into @dates( currentdate )
    select curr
        from cte

select a.CurrentDate, 
        b.operId, 
        b.Branch_No,
        b.I, 
        b.O 
    from @dates a 
    left outer join @inout b on b.clock_date = a.currentdate 
    order by a.currentdate, b.i
```

Comment: Sir, it is working, thank you, but one question, what are variables I should put on the stored procedure/ query? I mean, if the user ,month, and year are different, how I can control that?

Comment: Pass them as sql parameters to your stored procedure. Pass the year and month.

Comment: Okay sir, already pass them, but where I should put the month, year and operID in this query? Thank you.